# Swapping strings in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I'm looking to figure out how to use regular expressions to swap three sections of text separated by quotes/commas. For the purpose of this question I'll call them strings, though I'm not sure if that would be correct. An example is below:

```
"TEXT_MAP_CENTER","中央地点","Center of Map"
```

I need to swap the Japanese text in the second string with the English in the first, so it reads:

```
"TEXT_MAP_CENTER","Center of Map","中央地点"
```

This is just one line of about 4300+ and each string is unique. Thankfully, in this particular file each line is always three strings. There is a second file I need to do this in in which the text wraps.

In order to do this quickly I understand that there are ways to do this using regular expressions, but given that this isn't my normal area of expertise I'm having a real hard time with it. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
,(".*?"),(".*?")$
```

with

```
,\2,\1
```

The two `()` capture the two strings, which is referenced by `\1` and `\2` respectively. Then we replace the first with the second matched string and vice versa

If the strings contain newlines then you just need to select **`.` matches newlines** in the regex search option. An alternative way without enabling that option is

```
Find what:    ^("[^"]*"),("[^"]*"),("[^"]*")$
Replace with: \1,\3,\2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. This worked flawlessly - I did discover some bits of the file that contained entries that were split across multiple lines (they appear to wrap as if they need to fit a specific size text box). Would there be a similar method for this, or would it be better to edit these manually?

Comment: @TonyMarotta see my edit

Comment: if my answer helps you, could you please [accept it](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark?